# How to correctly use setq in elisp?

Tags: variables, emacs, elisp

In my emacs config I try to configure the project root for jedi using the following code:

```
(setq jedi:server-args '("--sys-path" (projectile-project-root)))
```

Which throws a:

```
deferred error : (wrong-type-argument stringp (projectile-project-root))
```

(I have `(setq debug-on-error t)` but the backtrace shows nothing)

If I hardcode the path like this all works as expected:

```
(setq jedi:server-args '("--sys-path" "/some/path"))
```

To give this line some context, here's the surrounding code:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq debug-on-error t)
(defun jedi-config:setup-server-args ()
  (message (format "Configuring current project dir: %s"
           (projectile-project-root)))
  (setq jedi:server-args '("--sys-path" (projectile-project-root))))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      'jedi-config:setup-server-args)
```

How can I set the server-args for jedi using the projectile variable?

Comment: Smells like a duplicate....

Comment: [The same problem in slightly different garb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449364/elisp-alist-and-strings-type-confusion/9449573#9449573).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out - rather simple really:

```
(setq jedi:server-args (list "--sys-path" (projectile-project-root)))
```

Comment: The link in my comment shows you how to do this using [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).